# Submitting HTML Form with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I've got a form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="hubForm">
    <label class="labelText">Expiration Date:</label>
    <input class="datBox" type="text" id="cal" name="date">
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <label class="labelText">Hub Name</label>
    <input class="inputTxt" type="text" value="" name="name" />
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <label class="labelText">Description</label>
    <textarea class="textArea" name="desc"></textarea>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <input class="submitButt" type="submit" value="" />
    <div class="clr"></div>
</form>
```

And I've got this JavaScript:

```
$('#hubForm').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "hubControl.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
});
```

And this PHP code:

```
//Add the hub, task, or project to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$type."s(".$IDvar.", name, description, users, expDate)
VALUES(".$ID.", \"".$_POST['title']."\", \"".$_POST['desc']."\", ".$ID.", ".$_POST['date'].")");
```

But it refuses to add anything to the database. I've rewritten the code to use $_GET and tested the PHP and I've verified that it works.

As for the JavaScript, I've also tried stuff like

```
$.post("hubControl.php", $('#hubForm').serialize());
```

but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
The form HTML was given to me by someone else, so I don't know if it's 100% compatible with the AJAX/JavaScript with stuff like the method="post". You will all have a better idea than I would.

Comment: Can you test with Fiddler ot Firebug to see what gets posted to the PHP page.. also, are you sure the $(this) refers to the form inside the ajax call.. I am not sure the context of this is the #hubForm..

Comment: I've tried it without the $this and using $('#hubForm') and $('hubForm') instead. I'll try to use Firebug, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Looks like Bobby is going to have another field day: [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) that is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works with $_GET and not $_POST, it sounds like the $_POST array is not being filled correctly.

I would recommend you start working through this by viewing your $_REQUEST or $_POST array when the page is loaded.  print_r($_POST) in some HTML pre tags can be very useful.

If you know that the PHP isn't even receiving the correct data, you can focus on fixing the Ajax/jQuery.

Comment: Also, please read up on MySQL injection and why you should sanitize any user input using mysql_real_escape();

Comment: I'm using a jQuery UI Dialog, so when I try to print anything on the PHP page, it just doesn't show anything. In fact, it may not be getting to the PHP file at all for all I know with my tests. I've also tried creating a submit() function and doing an onClick() and putting an alert() in the function, but nothing happened. I'll try the print_r($_POST) in a few minutes and see if anything comes up

Comment: If you print_r($POST) into your error log, it will be obvious if the page is even getting hit by the ajax query.. try something like:

$test = print_r($_POST,1);
error_log("----POST-----\n".$test);

Comment: It's definitely getting there and getting the values I'm sending. That helped me find the issue. I printed out my SQL query and, despite it working with $_GET, stuff is coming up empty and with extra commas. Time work on that

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you should consider using the [ajaxForm plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It's very easy to use, you can just drop it in to your project with minimal setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use uppercase type:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "hubControl.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize()
});
```